# Drools Check for Non-Existence isnt behaving like id expect

Tags: drools, rule-engine

relative new comer to drools and rules engines.

I have three rules that essentially check if different instances of the same object exist, if they don't, they create one and insert it into the working memory. After performing a series of other related rules, theres a rule that checks for validity of the models.

The goal here is to have three different instances of the same object that represent three different entities and proceed as long as 2 of them are in a valid state.

They're defined as follows:

```
rule "SetupA"
salience 80
lock-on-active
when
    not InvalidModel(name == "A-Name")
then
    InvalidModel invalidA = new InvalidModel();
    invalidA.setName("A-Name");
    insert(invalidA);
end

rule "SetupB"
salience 80
lock-on-active
when
    not InvalidModel(name == "B-Name")
then
    InvalidModel invalidB = new InvalidModel();
    invalidB.setName("B-Name");
    insert(invalidB);
end

rule "SetupC"
salience 80
lock-on-active
when
    not InvalidModel(name == "C-Name")
then
    InvalidModel invalidC = new InvalidModel();
    invalidC.setName("C-Name");
    insert(invalidC);
end

rule "VALIDATE_MODEL_FOR_ANY_INVALID_FLAGS"
salience -10
when
    $invalidList: List(size > 1) from collect(InvalidModel(isNotFound || isFlagged || isNotActive))
then
    setDecision(result, "Denied");
end
```

However, what's happening is that it seems like these rules are matched on every request to this ruleset which I interpret as the facts not existing in the Working Memory. I'd expect the rules to be fired once, when each of the facts for the respective names dont exist, and then to not fire again as there is nothing that would remove them from the working memory. However, my audit log of the rules that fire show that for every request those rules get fired.

Furthermore, the fourth rule's condition seems to not be performing as expected as it returns a response like such

```
=============== DEBUG MESSAGE: illegal bytecode sequence - method not verified ================
```

My ask is for some guidance on where my logic/drools language structure may have gone astray. Thanks for your time.

Comment: What type of `KieSession` are you using? A stateless or a stateful one?

Comment: Hi @EstebanAliverti, thanks for the response. Am using a Stateful KieSession presently. Also, reading your book right now, its been a very helpful resource.

Comment: Can you please include the code you are using to create the session, to feed the facts to it and to execute the rules?